# How to render list for ajax response in grails?

Tags: ajax, grails

I'm sending ajax response by jquery to grails action. There I generate some crazy thing like ArrayList> ( don't ask for what :D ) and want to send it to the javascript like "render list as List", but in js I get string contains this array. What is wrong?

Comment: Could you provide source code of this action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should send it as JSON, e.g.

```
def myAjaxAction() {
  def response = getResponse()
  render as JSON
}
```